# error exposed beyond app through Intent, open pdf file

Tags: android, kotlin

Through base64 string iam creating a pdf file.
This pdf file is succesfully created and stored in data/users/0/cache

On a button click i want to show this pdf file.

Function in kotlin:

```
fun decodeArbeidscontractString() {



var fos: FileOutputStream? = null


  try {
   
        f = File(context?.cacheDir, "newPdf_f.pdf")
        f!!.createNewFile()

        fos = FileOutputStream(f)
        val decodedString: ByteArray = Base64.decode(pdf_string_arbeidscontract, 
        Base64.DEFAULT)

        fos.write(decodedString) //write the base64 to the pdf
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()

val path: Uri = Uri.fromFile(f)

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf")
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)


try {
    startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {

}
```

}

I can see the file in the emulator but cannot open it. How can i do that

Comment: `val path: Uri = Uri.fromFile(f)` will give you a `FileUriExposedExceptions` since Android N.

Comment: ok, how can i solve this, i want to show the pdf file to user after button click

Comment: `FileUriExposedException`